# How to get the Parent's parent directory in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, path, scripting

So if I have a directory stored in a variable, say:

```
$scriptPath = (Get-ScriptDirectory);
```

Now I would like to find the directory *two* parent levels up.

I need a nice way of doing:

```
$parentPath = Split-Path -parent $scriptPath
$rootPath = Split-Path -parent $parentPath
```

Can I get to the rootPath in one line of code?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

### Version for a directory

`get-item` is your friendly helping hand here.

```
(get-item $scriptPath ).parent.parent
```

If you Want the string only

```
(get-item $scriptPath ).parent.parent.FullName
```

### Version for a file

If `$scriptPath` points to a file then you have to call `Directory` property on it first, so the call would look like this

```
(get-item $scriptPath).Directory.Parent.Parent.FullName
```

**Remarks**
This will only work if `$scriptPath` exists. Otherwise you have to use `Split-Path` cmdlet.

Comment: Awesome @rerun, that returns the directory object, what's the command to then return the path in a string?

Comment: `.parent` only works on directory objects.  If I have a path to a file, and I want to find the parent of the directory that the file is in, I need to use `(get-item $PathToFile ).Directory.parent`

Comment: Note that this works only when `$scriptPath` exists. Otherwise just use `Split-Path $scriptPath -parent`.

Comment: I have proposed a merge of @Baodad comment into your answer so it is more visible to other members of SO.

Comment: I had to explicitly set the `-Path` parameter like this `(get-item -Path $scriptPath ).parent.parent.FullName`

Answer (score 49):

I've solved that like this:

```
$RootPath = Split-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot -Parent) -Parent
```

Comment: `$RootPath = Split-Path (Split-Path $PSScriptRoot)` also works since `-Parent` is the default location split parameter for `Split-Path`

Comment: You can also use pipes if you don't like parentheses and want to read left-to-right `$RootPath = $PSScriptRoot | Split-Path | Split-Path`.

Answer (score 24):

You can split it at the backslashes, and take the next-to-last one with negative array indexing to get just the grandparent directory name.

```
($scriptpath -split '\\')[-2]
```

You have to double the backslash to escape it in the regex.

To get the entire path:

```
($path -split '\\')[0..(($path -split '\\').count -2)] -join '\'
```

And, looking at the parameters for split-path, it takes the path as pipeline input, so:

```
$rootpath = $scriptpath | split-path -parent | split-path -parent
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
(get-item $scriptPath).Directoryname
```

to get the string path or if you want the Directory type use:

```
(get-item $scriptPath).Directory
```

Answer (score 14):

You can simply chain as many `split-path` as you need:

```
$rootPath = $scriptPath | split-path | split-path
```

Answer (score 8):

### simplest solution

Here's the simplest solution

`"$path\..\.."`

If you want to get an absolute path, you can

`"$path\..\.." | Convert-Path`

### reusable solution

Here is a reusable solution, first define the getParent function, then call it directly.

```
function getParent($path, [int]$deep = 1) {
    $result = $path | Get-Item | ForEach-Object { $_.PSIsContainer ? $_.Parent : $_.Directory }
    for ($deep--; $deep -gt 0; $deep--) { $result = getParent $result }
    return $result
}
```

```
getParent $scriptPath 2
```

Answer (score 6):

In PowerShell 3, `$PsScriptRoot` or for your question of two parents up,

```
$dir = ls "$PsScriptRoot\..\.."
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Split-Path -Path (Get-Location).Path -Parent
```

Answer (score 5):

To extrapolate a bit on the other answers (in as Beginner-friendly a way as possible):

- String objects that point to valid paths can be converted to DirectoryInfo/FileInfo objects via functions like Get-Item and Get-ChildItem.
- .Parent can only be used on a DirectoryInfo object.
- .Directory converts a FileInfo object to a DirectoryInfo object (targeting the file's directory), and will return null if used on any other type *(even another DirectoryInfo object)*.
- .DirectoryName converts a FileInfo object to a String object (targeting the file's directory), and will return null if used on any other type *(even another String object)*.
- .FullName converts a DirectoryInfo/FileInfo object to a String object, and will return null if used on any other type *(even another DirectoryInfo/FileInfo object)*.
- .Path converts a PathInfo object to a String object, and will return null if used on any other type *(even another PathInfo object)*.

Check the object type with the GetType Method to see what you're working with: `$scriptPath.GetType()`

Lastly, a quick tip that helps with making one-liners: Get-Item has the `gi` alias and Get-ChildItem has the `gci` alias.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the corresponding handling methods when the type is `FileInfo`, `DirectoryInfo`, or `String`:

- [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-7.0): $myPath.[DirectoryName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.directoryname?view=net-7.0)
- [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-7.0): $myPath.[Parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.parent?view=net-7.0).[FullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.parent?view=net-7.0#remarks)
- String: `$myPath | Split-Path`

### Example

```
function Get-ParentPath {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [object]$myPath
    )
    switch ($myPath.GetType().Name) {
        "FileInfo" { echo "FileInfo: $($myPath.DirectoryName)" } # path must exist Otherwise will get the error
        "DirectoryInfo" { echo "DirectoryInfo: $($myPath.Parent.FullName)" } # path must exist Otherwise will get the error
        "String" { $myPath | Split-Path } # it's ok when the path does not exist
        default { Write-Host "Unknown type" }
    }
}

# test
Get-ParentPath (Get-Item "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe")
Get-ParentPath (Get-Item "C:\Windows\System32")
Get-ParentPath ("C:\bar\foo\notExistsDir")
Get-ParentPath ("C:\bar\foo\notExistsDir\abc.txt")
```

output:

```
FileInfo: C:\Windows\System32
DirectoryInfo: C:\Windows
C:\bar\foo
C:\bar\foo\notExistsDir
```

Answer (score 0):

In powershell :

```
$this_script_path = $(Get-Item $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)).DirectoryName

$parent_folder = Split-Path $this_script_path -Leaf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $PSScriptRoot you can do

```
Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath ..\.. -Resolve
```