# Get root folder of a network share

Tags: powershell

How to get root folder of a network share in PowerShell?

For eg from

\network\myfolder1\folder2\files\

How to get : \network

Answer (score 0):

You can check this posting for some examples on the subject.

[How to get the Parent's parent directory in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725521/how-to-get-the-parents-parent-directory-in-powershell)

I usually use something like this.

```
$s = "\\network\myfolder1\folder2\files\"
$s.Split("\")[2]
```

This gives you the folder name itself of "network"

You could modify the last line to pad it with UNC slashes like this

```
$( "\\" + $s.Split("\")[2])
```