# How to simply extract leading N parts of a path?

Tags: powershell, path, split

I've got a bunch of directory names and file names, some are absolute path, some are relative path. I just wish to get the 2 leading parts of each path. Input:

```
D:\a\b\c\d.txt\
c:\a
\my\desk\n.txt
you\their\mine
```

I expect to get:

```
D:\a
c:\a
\my\desk
you\their
```

Is there a convenient way in PowerShell to achieve this?

Comment: I don't use power shell but I googled it https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849809.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Split-Path -Parent , nested if required....

Comment: Split-path as suggested by others. There is also a -Depth switch on get-childitem that might come in handy (with -recurse) in PowerShell 5.0 you can use this will some filtering for powerful results.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question] ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/9725521/847990)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sometimes get your hand slapped for suggesting string manipulation as it can sometimes be "unreliable". However your test data contains 3 different possibilities. Also, never seen someone looking for the *first part**s*** from a path.

I present a simple solution the nets your desired output as you have it in your question

```
"D:\a\b\c\d.txt\","c:\a","\my\desk\n.txt","you\their\mine" | ForEach-Object{
    ($_ -split "(?<=\S)\\")[0..1] -join "\"
}
```

I needed to use a lookbehind since your sample output contains a leading a leading slash that you wanted to retain. It splits every string on slashes that have a non white-space character in front of them.

This would not return the correct path for UNC's. `Split-Path` would be the obvious choice if you only wanted a single portion of the path. I suppose you could nest the call to get 2 but at this time I am unable to find a simple way to account for all of your examples with the same logic.

Comment: Thanks, but would you help to explain what "(?<=\S)\\" actually means? I don't quite the "?" and "<=", and Capital "S"

Comment: @Matt +1 for regex, I will have to get my head around those one day... Also, this does not work for UNC paths "\\bob\c$\temp", would that be easy to fix?

Comment: @viksantata `?<=` is a so-called positive look-behind assertion. In your case it limits matches to backslashes preceded by a non-space character. Without that `\my\desk\n.txt` would become `\my` instead of `\my\desk`.